# Extracting certain data from txt file

Tags: python, pandas, outlook, win32com, txt

I'm trying to get a certain amount of data from a txt file. The data looks like this:

```
Client:   x                                                                                                       
Project:  x                                                                                                            
Order:    xxxx-xxxx-xxxx                                                                                                            
Run:      x                                                                                                                        
Copy:     x                                                                                                                        
Batch:    x

Totals Provided by Client                                                                                                           
Description                                        DOCUMENTS     SHEETS      PAGES                                                  
 ------------------------------------------------- ----------- ----------- -----------                                               
   INPUT1_xxxxxx_170014260_20230316.pdf                     92          46          92                                               
   INPUT2_xxxxxx_200406_20230316.pdf                        18          18          36                                               
   INPUT2_xxxxxx_200806_20230316.pdf                      20         139         278                                               
   INPUT1_xxxxxx_200012_20230316.pdf                        48         288         576                                               
   INPUT1_xxxxxx_200034312_20230316.pdf                    100         342         684                                               
   INPUT1_xxxxxx_200116_20230316.pdf                        49         343         686                                               
   INPUT1_xxxxxx_200326_20230316.pdf                       100         400         800                                               
   INPUT1_xxxxxx_200342_20230316.pdf                       100         100         200                                               
   INPUT1_xxxxxx_200346_20230316.pdf                     100         684        1368                                               
   INPUT2_xxxxxx_200233221_20230316.pdf                     62         262         524                                               
   INPUT2_xxxxxxx_200416_20230316.pdf                         6          24          48                                               
                                                   ----------- ----------- -----------                                               
    Total Client Totals                                   695        2646        5292                                               
                                                   =========== =========== ===========
```

I've already gotten the Client through Batch information using indexing, but the Description section is going to be a different length in each file, some don't end in .pdf and some don't start with "INPUT1" so how can I get that section of data for each file without knowing how big the section is going to be? The data is coming from Outlook attachments, they're being put into a folder on my machine and renamed, then I am going into the txt file and pulling out the data I need.

I know I can use indexing to get it, but that doesn't help for the files that are different. Here's the code I'm using, I know it's messy and needs clean up, but right now I'm just trying to get this data out. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

```
from pathlib import Path
import win32com.client
import os
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from datetime import datetime as dt
import re

def save_attachments(folder_name):
    output_dir = Path.cwd() / "Attachments"
    print(type(output_dir))
    output_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
    mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    inbox =  mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders[folder_name]
    donebox =  mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders["done_box"]
    txt_file = []
    found = []
    match = re.compile('Description')

    for message in inbox.Items:
            attachments = message.Attachments
            for attachment in attachments:
                sent_date = message.SentOn.strftime("%m_%d_%y")
                new_name = str(attachment).split(".")[2] + "_" + sent_date + ".txt"
                attachment.SaveAsFile(output_dir / new_name)
                # message.Delete()
                # message.Move(donebox)
    for f_name in os.listdir(output_dir):
            os.chdir(output_dir)
            with open(f_name) as f:
                lines = f.readlines()
                for line in lines[1:]:
                    txt_file.append(line.split())

                project_type = txt_file[2][1]
                order_num = txt_file[3][1]
                run_num = txt_file[4][1]
                copy_num = txt_file[5][1]
                batch_num = txt_file[6][1]
                sent_date_2 = message.SentOn.strftime("%m.%d.%y %H: %M: %S")
                sheets_names = message.SentOn.strftime("%B")

            l1 = str(attachment)
            l2 = project_type
            l3 = order_num
            l4 = run_num
            l5 = copy_num
            l6 = batch_num
            l7 = sent_date_2
            l8 = " "
            dict_1 = {"File" : l1, "Project" : l2, "Order": l3, "Run": l4, "Copy": l5, "Batch": l6, "When": l7, "Description": l8}
            df = DataFrame(dict_1, index=[0])
            print(df)
            print(df['Project'].tolist())
            df.to_csv("test.csv", header=False, index=False)
```

I've tried using islice and I've tried indexing. Probably other methods as well I just can't remember.

EDIT:

```
    output_dir = Path.cwd() / "RRD Reconciliation Attachments"
    output_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
    mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    inbox =  mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders[folder_name]
    donebox =  mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders["done_box"]
    txt_file = []
    flat_list = []


    for message in inbox.Items:
            attachments = message.Attachments
            for attachment in attachments:
                sent_date = message.SentOn.strftime("%m_%d_%y")
                new_name = str(attachment).split(".")[2] + "_" + sent_date + ".txt"
                attachment.SaveAsFile(output_dir / new_name)
                # sheets_names = message.SentOn.strftime("%B")

                # message.Delete()
                # message.Move(donebox)
    for f_name in os.listdir(output_dir):
            os.chdir(output_dir)


            with open(f_name) as data:
                details = False
                skip = False
                columns = []
                d = {}
                for line in map(str.rstrip, data):
                    if skip:
                        skip = False
                        continue
                    tokens = line.split()
                    if len(tokens) == 0:
                        continue
                    if details:
                        if len(tokens) != len(columns):
                            break
                        for token, column in zip(tokens, columns):
                            d.setdefault(column, []).append(token)
                    else:
                        if tokens[0] == 'Description':
                            details = True
                            skip = True
                            columns = tokens

                        else:
                            if len(tokens) == 2 and tokens[0][-1] == ':':
                                d[tokens[0][:-1]] = tokens[1]
            dict_list = []
            dict_list.append(d)
            dict_group = dict_list[0]

            data_f = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_group)
            data_f = data_f.drop(columns=['DOCUMENTS', 'SHEETS*', 'PAGES*'], errors='ignore')
            data_f.to_excel("test.xlsx", sheet_name='Month', index=False)
```

I'm using this to put multiple files in an excel sheet when the DataFrame is created it, it shows the data of two sample files I'm working with, but when I do .to_excel() its only giving me one of the dictionaries in the spreadsheet. I'm assuming the data is getting "renamed" when the loop is happening, but I don't know how to fix that. If anyone has any ideas, I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: nothing will happen if you don't call the function

Comment: why do you do a regex compile of a literal string

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract all files started by 'INPUT' and ended by .pdf, try this:

```
with open("file.txt") as f: #open your txt file
    data=f.read() 
    idx=0
    while True:
        idxstart=data.find("INPUT",idx) 
        if idxstart==-1:break #end of files
        idx=data.find(".pdf",idxstart)+4
        file=data[idxstart:idx] #find founded
        print(file)
```

I not actually tested this, adjust this code.

Comment: I was going to try that, but other files that will be looked at, the invoices don't start with "INPUT1" or end in .pdf.

Comment: why do you have the `while True` indented in the context manager?, what is the use of `idx=0`

Comment: @crossxbreaker if you don't give examples of the other cases we don't know and don't handle them

Comment: @crossxbreaker maybe can you tell the other excepted files, the code i provided is to extract all start by `INPUT`, you can replace this by `INPUT1` to ignore `INPUT2` files. I don't really understand what other files are you talked

Comment: @rioV8 `while True` is to display many files, and `idx=0` is to not generate an error in `idxstart=data.find("INPUT",idx)`. Have you tried the code without them?

Comment: `while True` does not need to be indented, and oops I did not see the `idx` as argument in `find`

Comment: Yes, you're right. anyway it doesn't change anything if `while True` it's indented or not

Comment: I'm pulling all the attachments from my outlook email, then the files are saved to my machine, I change the name to have the data I want in the filename, then I am taking the information from the files and I'm saving it to an excel spreadsheet. The issue is this file says INPUT1_yadda_yadda_yadda.pdf, but another attachment I pull from outlook may have an invoice in the description that is just 09989_93834_13452 no INPUT and no .pdf, so I wasn't able to just pull strings that either start with INPUT or end in .pdf.

Comment: I don’t really understand what you want, maybe the regex module can help you to filtre your files

Answer (score 0):

You can make this more dynamic by identifying where the document details start. There's a line that starts with 'Description' and on that line are, effectively, a number of column headings. With that knowledge we can do this:

```
import json # just for output formatting

with open('/Volumes/G-Drive/data.txt') as data:
    details = False
    skip = False
    columns = []
    d = {}
    for line in map(str.rstrip, data):
        if skip:
            skip = False
            continue
        if len(tokens := line.split()) == 0:
            continue # blank line
        if details:
            if len(tokens) != len(columns):
                break # finished
            for token, column in zip(tokens, columns):
                d.setdefault(column, []).append(token)
        else:
            if tokens[0] == 'Description':
                details = True
                skip = True
                columns = tokens
            else:
                if len(tokens) == 2 and tokens[0][-1] == ':':
                    d[tokens[0][:-1]] = tokens[1]
    print(json.dumps(d, indent=2))
```

For my testing I modified the first part of the data file to look like this:

```
Client:   client_1                                                                    
Project:  project_1                                                                   
Order:    xxxx-xxxx-xxxx                                                              
Run:      run_1                                                                       
Copy:     copy_1                                                                                                         
Batch:    batch_1
```

...just to get some meaningful data rather than just Xs

We then get this output:

```
{
  "Client": "client_1",
  "Project": "project_1",
  "Order": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx",
  "Run": "run_1",
  "Copy": "copy_1",
  "Batch": "batch_1",
  "Description": [
    "INPUT1_xxxxxx_170014260_20230316.pdf",
    "INPUT2_xxxxxx_200406_20230316.pdf",
    "INPUT2_xxxxxx_200806_20230316.pdf",
    "INPUT1_xxxxxx_200012_20230316.pdf",
    "INPUT1_xxxxxx_200034312_20230316.pdf",
    "INPUT1_xxxxxx_200116_20230316.pdf",
    "INPUT1_xxxxxx_200326_20230316.pdf",
    "INPUT1_xxxxxx_200342_20230316.pdf",
    "INPUT1_xxxxxx_200346_20230316.pdf",
    "INPUT2_xxxxxx_200233221_20230316.pdf",
    "INPUT2_xxxxxxx_200416_20230316.pdf"
  ],
  "DOCUMENTS": [
    "92",
    "18",
    "20",
    "48",
    "100",
    "49",
    "100",
    "100",
    "100",
    "62",
    "6"
  ],
  "SHEETS": [
    "46",
    "18",
    "139",
    "288",
    "342",
    "343",
    "400",
    "100",
    "684",
    "262",
    "24"
  ],
  "PAGES": [
    "92",
    "36",
    "278",
    "576",
    "684",
    "686",
    "800",
    "200",
    "1368",
    "524",
    "48"
  ]
}
```

...which can easily be transformed into a DataFrame if needed.

There is a potential problem with this approach if/when the description is made up of more than one token

Comment: What do you mean "There is a potential problem with this approach if/when the description is made up of more than one token"?

Comment: @crossxbreaker What if the description is "green bananas"?

Comment: So I'm running this with multiple files and its giving me two dictionaries with the value of d when using the code you provided. When I turn it into a df it works file, but when I write it to excel it only gives me the last dictionary in the excel sheet. I've attached the code in my original post.